# Cannot send mail due "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

the config in **development.rb** file

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_methods = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      address: "my.smtp.com",
      port: 25,
      authentication: "plain",
      domain: "example.com",
      openssl_verify_mode: :none,
      enable_starttls_auto: false,
      user_name: "username",
      password:  "password"
  }
```

code in my controller:

```
mail(:to => "example@gmail.com", :subject => "test")
```

I have installed:

> ruby 2.0  rails (4.1.0) actionmailer (= 4.1.0)

Comment: What does the stack trace of the error say?

Comment: error is not with the mail settings. It has to do with some code in the mail method or from where you are fetching data where there is typecast error

Comment: This is the framework trace @maniacalrobot http://pasted.co/5f8d355a

Comment: Hi, thanks for pasting the trace, unfortunately, this is only the "framework" trace, which does't include any lines from your application. There should be options for "application" and "all", generally to help debug issues, you should use the "all" stack trace.

Comment: Thanks @maniacalrobot, this is full trace http://pasted.co/2a739417

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a spelling mistake when defining the actionmailer delivery method. Try using the singular of delivery_method:

```rb
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

Answer (score 0):

The controller code seems incorrect to me...
Try this instead?

`mail(:to => "example@gmail.com", :subject => "test")`

Comment: Thanks you're right I had a typo but I tried again and I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

According to the ActionMailer Docs, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration the `openssl_verify_mode: :none` should either use a string `'none'`, or the `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` constant from the openssl gem. I think this is how you're getting a “no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer” error. Personally I'd try:

```rb
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "my.smtp.com",
  port: 25,
  authentication: "plain",
  domain: "example.com",
  openssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
  enable_starttls_auto: false,
  user_name: "username",
  password:  "password"
}
```

Comment: I tried both with 'none' and constant one, I get the same error.